# Web API CORS implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

First let me say I understand the concept of CORS and mostly how it works, but I have a very specific question about how it's implemented in Microsoft's Web API.  I've configured CORS in the `Global.ascx.cs` file like this:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://example.com", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Now, when I request a resource in our web api with the header `Origin: https://example.com` I get a response that contains the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`, which is expected.  But when I request the same resource with a different `Origin` value or without that header altogether, the response from the server does not have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Is this the desired result?  Or should the server always respond back with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

I'm asking because we've had Veracode scan our codebase, and they are saying the response should always have the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com` present.  From what I understand, browsers will still throw the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` whether the header is there with a different origin or if the header is not there at all (and I would think that not disclosing the allowed domains would be the preferred solution).

Also, I do know that I can make the header always show by adding this to my `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://example.com" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

But I'm really just wondering what the correct implementation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is by design:

> If the response does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, the AJAX request fails. Specifically, the browser disallows the request. Even if the server returns a successful response, the browser does not make the response available to the client application.

Linked article contains full explanation in ***How CORS works*** section.

It also provides info when browser is sending preflight requests and how to enable headers Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Header in preflight request

[Enabling CORS in Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Specification also tells that response might include this header with proper value to allow access to resource, but does not have to include it in case resource should not be available for client

> An HTTP response to a CORS request can include the following headers:
>
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
>
> Indicates whether the response can be shared, via returning the literal value of the `Origin` request header (which can be `null`) or `*` in a response.

[Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-access-control-allow-origin)

**edit**

More explicit from [W3 Recomendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header), that resource that does not allow access from other origins should not include Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

> A resource that is not useful to applications from other origins, such as a login page, ought not to return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The resource still must protect itself against CSRF attacks, such as by requiring the inclusion of an unguessable token in the explicitly provided content of the request. The security properties of such resources are unaffected by user-agents conformant to this specification.

Comment: this is what I had thought, but couldn't find any documentation on it.  So since our web api is following standards, why would Veracode request that we change it?

Comment: Not sure, I would ask them to explain the reason. I agree with you that disclosing valid origin is potentially dangerous

Comment: yea that's what we'll have to do, I just wanted some information to back up my thoughts. Thanks!